# How to add customize userinfo table to auth_user_groups in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a user table 'UserInfo' and created two groups 'admin' and 'normal users' given some permissions to these groups.

I am adding the users to a particular group based on the type of the user i.e if user is admin I will give the permissions of the admin to that user.

Now I want to check whether a particular user has_perm or not, and also I want to add the user to the table auth_user_group. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Each user has a `groups` ManyToManyManager that will list their groups. If you want to add a user to a group, use the [`ManyToManyManager` api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
g = Group.objects.get(name='admin')
u.groups.add(g)
u.save()
u.groups.remove(g)
u.save()
```

Once you add a user to a group, they will inherit all permissions of that group. There is no equivalent of `has_perm` that checks if a user is in a group or not, but there is [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) which you can use to check if a user passes any condition. It works by calling any function you define with the user object:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.shortcuts import render

def is_admin(user):
   return user.group_set.filter(name='admin').count()

@user_passes_test(is_admin)
def only_admin(request):
    return render(request, 'sekret.html')
```

Comment: u = User.objects.get(pk=1) in this the User table is from auth_models but I have my own custom userinfo table.how to add that table to the Group and check the permissions?

Comment: Create a group many to many field in your custom model and point it to the Group model from django.contrib.auth.

Comment: userobj = UserInfo.objects.get(email='@example.com')
userobj.group_set.filter(name='Admin').count()
gives me UserInfo object has no attrib group_set

Comment: Yes, because you didn't update your `UserInfo` model.