# In django, Select group of user while creating User

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to do a simple task as follows.

I want to show all user group in form as radio buttons (so that a new user can belong to only one group)

on save button, I want to set selected group as group of newly created user.

here is my forms.py

```
class UserGroupForm( forms.Form ):
    CHOICES = [( group.name, group.name ) for group in Group.objects.all()]
    name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget = forms.widgets.RadioSelect())
```

here is my views.py

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.has_key( 'save' ):
            usergroupform = UserGroupForm(request.POST)
            if usergroupform.is_valid():
                new_user = user_form.save()
                name = usergroupform.cleaned_data('name')
                g = Group.objects.get(name)
                new_user.groups.add(g)
    else:
        user_form = OS_UserForm()
        usergroupform = UserGroupForm()
    resp_dict = {'user_form':user_form,'UserGroupForm':usergroupform}
    render_to_response( "assign_group.html", resp_dict )
```

here is my template assign_group.html

```
{{ UserGroupForm.name }}
```

I assure that has_key is working correctly.(& not displayed in template) because above code is a part of create_user page.
it was working correctly. but i want to just add the functionality to select group while creating user :)

I am getting following error

TypeError ......
'Group' object is not iterable

I got some reference from below:

[How to add customize userinfo table to auth_user_groups in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804237/how-to-add-customize-userinfo-table-to-auth-user-groups-in-django)

Comment: Can you tell us where this exception/error is raised? Is it a Problem of forms.py? This you can test if you remove the Group queryset in forms.py and insert a manually created list.

Comment: It should work flawlessly. Likely, the problem is somewhere in your code (place some more).